# heyoo is not sending messages

Tags: python, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am trying the following code:

```
from heyoo import WhatsApp
messenger = WhatsApp(my_token,phone_number_id=my_phone_id)
# For sending a Text messages
messenger.send_message('Hello I am WhatsApp Cloud API', registered_number)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
{'messaging_product': 'whatsapp',
 'contacts': [{'input': 'XXXXXXXX', 'wa_id': 'XXXXXXX'}],
 'messages': [{'id': 'wamid.HBgMOTcyJKEzMjY4ODg5FQIAERgGHzAyQzE3RDg5NURDQjc0OEFFAA=='}]}
```

But no message is received.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Solved!!

For some reason - only after I sent a message to the test number from my mobile- I succeded receiving the messages form my code.

Don't understand why...

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes. Wrote about the solution in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

The one and only thing you need to do is reply to the first message you receive in your WhatsApp. So, go to your phone and type whatever you want and then send. After replying to the message on your phone everything should work correctly.